# Why is DrawPolygon cutting off? It is not drawing fully

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use visual basic to draw a triangle. I am using Graphics.DrawPolygon(). Only a bit of the triangle actually gets drawn, the other part is cut off. Why is this happening?

I tried drawing rectangles, pies, and lines. The problem exists for all three.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim yes As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim myPen As Pen
    Dim A As New Point(100, 100)
    Dim B As New Point(500, 100)
    Dim C As New Point(300, 500)
    Dim points As Point() = {a, b, c}
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Black, 1)
        yes.DrawPolygon(myPen, points)
    End Sub
End Class
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10MOH4PKv5mVRzV6TsHC_T_O86ugTJw2q/view?usp=sharing
Link above is a screenshot of the program running. it is supposed to be a triangle. please help!

Comment: Just one of the *many* problems caused by CreateGraphics.  The Graphics object is stale and has the clipping region of the old uninitialized window.  Which was much smaller.  Never do this, use the Paint event.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I will look into it. Also, around how big is the uninitialized window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the graphics stuff on a picturebox. solved!